# SpringTest and afterPropertiesSet

Tags: spring, easymock, spring-test

I use SpringTest and EasyMock to do unit testing on my Spring bean.

My test bean is like this:

```
    @ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/test/applicationContext-test.xml")
    public class ControllerTest {

        @Autowired
        private Controller controller;

        @Autowired
        private IService service;

        @Test
        public void test() {
        }
}
```

Here is my Controller:

```
@Controller
@Scope("request")
public class Controller implements InitializingBean {

    @Autowired
    private IService service;

    void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        service.doSomething();
    }

}
```

The afterPropertiesSet method is automatically called by Spring when it initializes the bean. I would like to mock with EasyMock the call to doSomething method.

I though to do this in my test method but the afterPropertiesSet is executed before to go in my test method because Spring calls it when it initializes the bean.

How can I mock my service present in the afterPropertiesSet method with SpringTest or EasyMock ?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

I specifies that the mocked service is correctly loaded in my Controller by Spring. My problem is not how to create the mock (it's already ok) but how to mock the method.

Answer (score 2):

You are not providing enough details, so I'll give you an example with Mockito. Add this `IService` mock configuration to the *beginning* of `applicationContext-test.xml` file:

```
<bean 
      id="iServiceMock"
      class="org.mockito.Mockito" 
      factory-method="mock"
      primary="true">
  <constructor-arg value="com.example.IService"/>
</bean>
```

Noticed the `primary="true"` attribute? Spring will now find two classes implementing `IService` interface. But one of them is *primary* and it will be chosen for autowiring. That's it!

Want to record or verify some behaviour? Just inject this mock to your test:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/test/applicationContext-test.xml")
public class ControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  private IService iServiceMock;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't `@Autowire` your Controller, instead instantiate it programmatically in your test, setting the mocked service manually.

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Controller controller = new Controller();
    controller.setMyService(mockService);
}
```

or:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Controller controller = new Controller();
    controller.afterPropertiesSet();
}
```

Comment: Your solution assume I have a set for my controller and it's not the case. I would like to use autowired to have a Spring context.

Comment: @Kiva Why not create a package-level setter for your service? It will only be available to classes in the same package, such as your test class.